# How to customize google chart labels data outside center

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization, donut-chart

Js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rg4zsybf/2/

How can I make the UI look like shown in the below image.

[image: That image]

I want the **percentages should appear outside of the chart**, exactly like how it is present the below image.

I am not that good in google chart customization help is appreciated thanks.

With

```
pieSliceText: 'none',
sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
```

I can put outside, but I want something like shown in the image! is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Pie Chart is not entirely customizable. At least the documentation does not provide that. You can get pretty close to what you want. Use the pieHole parameter to achieve the donut shape.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwup6x0y/

```
var options = {
    title: 'Indian Language Use',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    legend: 'none',
    pieHole: 0.9,
    pieSliceText: 'none',
    legend: {
        position: 'labeled'
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not asking about pie hole, I want labels outside pie like shown in image